# Android - Positioning Bitmaps on canvas varying per device. How to handle?

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

My situation involves drawing a background where other objects are contained within regions of the background, for the sake of bounding.  I set up my surface view drawing to layout my bitmaps in the correct positions, but as soon as I tested on a different device, things were not in their correct positions.

I refactored my code to be less specific and based all my calculations off the center of the canvas (which is a requirement of my given images).  Given that my other objects have to be retained in specific regions of the image, I thought that I could figure out the x-y positions on the mdpi image and attempt to scale my positions based on scale of the canvas.  Didn't work.  I'm not really sure what else to try at this point.

```
//Center of canvas
float centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
float centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;

mDrawingMatrix.reset();
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(-(mBackground.getWidth() / 2), -(mBackground.getHeight() / 2));
mDrawingMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, mDrawingMatrix, null);

mDrawingMatrix.reset();
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(-(mFlatBobble.getWidth() / 2), -(mFlatBobble.getHeight() / 2));
mDrawingMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(centerX-(10 * mScale), centerY + (50 * mScale));
canvas.drawBitmap(mFlatBobble, mDrawingMatrix, null);

mDrawingMatrix.reset();
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(-(mBobble.getWidth() / 2), -(mBobble.getHeight() / 2));
mDrawingMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(centerX + (68 * mScale), centerY + (78 * mScale));
canvas.drawBitmap(mBobble, mDrawingMatrix, null);

mDrawingMatrix.reset();
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(-(mMask.getWidth() / 2), -(mMask.getHeight() / 2));
mDrawingMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
canvas.drawBitmap(mMask, mDrawingMatrix, null);
```

**EDIT2:Code below is obsolete.  Please see the answer I added below.**

**EDIT:** The working code now looks like:

```
//In the constructor...
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
mTargetScreenXRatio = (float)(dm.widthPixels / 480);
mTargetScreenYRatio = (float)(dm.heightPixels / 320);

//Center of canvas
float centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
float centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;

mDrawingMatrix.reset();
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(-(mBackground.getWidth() / 2), -(mBackground.getHeight() / 2));
mDrawingMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, mDrawingMatrix, null);

mDrawingMatrix.reset();
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(-(mFlatBobble.getWidth() / 2), -(mFlatBobble.getHeight() / 2));
mDrawingMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(centerX-(10 * mScale * mTargetScreenXRatio), centerY + (50 * mScale * mTargetScreenYRatio));
canvas.drawBitmap(mFlatBobble, mDrawingMatrix, null);

mDrawingMatrix.reset();
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(-(mBobble.getWidth() / 2), -(mBobble.getHeight() / 2));
mDrawingMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(centerX + (68 * mScale * mTargetScreenXRatio), centerY + (78 * mScale * mTargetScreenYRatio));
canvas.drawBitmap(mBobble, mDrawingMatrix, null);

mDrawingMatrix.reset();
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(-(mMask.getWidth() / 2), -(mMask.getHeight() / 2));
mDrawingMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
canvas.drawBitmap(mMask, mDrawingMatrix, null);
```

Comment: Are you drawing your bitmaps from /assets/ or /resources/? If you are getting them from /resources/drawables you will get different bitmaps depending on device screen size. This might be causing the problem.

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon I'm drawing from resources, but I've only got mdpi images at the moment.  If it becomes an issue, I'll move them to the assets folder.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your issue is the same I usually have, I solved it by calculating myself the proportions based on the current screen resolution.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

screenW = dm.widthPixels;
screenH = dm.heightPixels;

X = (float) screenW / 480;
Y = (float) screenH / 800;
```

480 * 800 is my reference screen size, you can change it to what you prefer as your reference screen size.

At this point you just have to multiply your coordinates by X and Y to get the right proportions.

Comment: I should do this along with multiplying by the scale of the images as well, right?  I'm about to try it out.

Comment: And the answer to my comment question was yes.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

While I will not change the accepted answer, I actually went about this slightly differently.  Instead of hand calculating the resolution changes by checking the `dm.widthPixels` and such, I found a much better way to do it.

The code instead would be:

```
//Trimmed for brevity.
//In the constructor...
//mDisplayMetrics is a private variable in the class.
this.mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
//I no longer need the target ratio variables anymore.

float bobblePosX = centerX - (TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, this.mDisplayMetrics) * mScale);
float bobblePosY = centerY + (TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, this.mDisplayMetrics) * mScale);

mDrawingMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
mDrawingMatrix.postTranslate(bobblePosX, bobblePosY);
canvas.drawBitmap(mFlatBobble, mDrawingMatrix, null);
```

In the above code, I changed from multiplying the target screen ratio values that I had previously by the position from the mdpi value I wanted.  I also still need to scale the positions slightly because the images don't always match the screen resolution.

Hope this helps someone out!